# How to type antd form validateFields' callback parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

As the question title said: how to type the form.validateFields callback parameters when using Form HOC in Ant Design?

```
// App.tsx
import { FormComponentProps } from 'antd/lib/form';

interface IProps extends FormComponentProps { ... }

class App extends React.Component<IProps> {
  ...
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const { form } = this.props
    // the `err` and `values` has `any` type
    // how can I type them, or at least type values?
    form.validateFields((err, values) => { ... }))
  }
  ...
}

export default Form.create<IProps>()(App);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok my bad, after just a few steps digging the `Form.d.ts` source code I found the answer.

The `FormComponentPrps` accepts a generic type which is `any` by default, adding the generic could type the `values` parameter of `form.validateFields` callback:

```
import { FormComponentProps } from 'antd/lib/form';

interface IFields {
  name: string;
  password: string;
}

interface IProps extends FormComponentProps<IFields> { ... }
```

BTW, the `err` parameter seems will always be `any` type

Answer (score 1):

in Antd v4 validating fields is done as follows:

```js
// antd v4
validateFields().then(values => {
  // Do something with value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to type `create()` too:

```js
// App.tsx
interface UserFormProps extends FormComponentProps {}

...
handleSubmit = () => {
  const { form } = this.props
  form.validateFields((err : any, values: any) => { ... }))
}
...
export default Form.create<UserFormProps>()(App);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, updated code. This doesn't solve the problem though~

Comment: What is the problem it not solving? now your values are typed, choose whatever you wish

Comment: ?? the `err` and `values` parameters are still `any` as before, your demo code even explicitly type then as `any', did I miss anything?

Comment: You can check the function signature what it accepts, what do you mean "they are still `any`"

Comment: Guess I didn't describe the question clear enough... See I want to use properties of the `values` parameter within `form.validateFields`' callback, but by default the `err` and `values` parameters are both `any` type, I'd like to get autocompletion or type checking when I use the `values`' property like `values.password` etc. So the question is how to get the `values` typed or how can I manually type it . Your answer doesn't help with this , but it does solve another type warning I have.